# What are the directories and files that I should keep in sync for a cluster server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, cluster

I am currently wanting to set up new clusters.

Each cluster is defined by its software installed, software settings, and its home folder files.

I want only the above to be cloned and not things like:

- `/etc/network/interfaces`
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- `/etc/hostname`

And please help with other things that need to be unique so that not to cause the system to malfunction? For example when reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) article on tar backups, I noticed that they said not to include

> "/proc, /sys, /mnt, /media, /run and /dev directories in root"

---

So what I am wanting to be able to do is, create a new ubuntu 14.04 LTS server from [scaleway.com](https://www.scaleway.com/) and send a .tar across with all the system files needed above. After that I will be expected to customise the `/etc/network/interfaces`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, `/etc/hostname` and whatever else you think I need to(?) And then I would like to use `sshfs` to keep all the important system files (as mentioned above) between the clusters in sync that I may want to edit in the future.

---

I tried backing up the main cluster like this:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf /fullBackup.tar.gz --one-file-system --exclude=/proc exclude=/tmp --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys /
```

and then running this on the new [scaleway.com](https://www.scaleway.com/) cluster after moving `fullBackup.tar.gz`:

```
sudo tar -xvpzf /fullBackup.tar.gz -C / --numeric-owner
```

but I just start recieving lots of `Exec format errors`? (I think it may have something to do with the ARM architecture from a PI to a [scaleway.com](https://www.scaleway.com/) server [an issue that I want to irradicate]) This is an example of backing up wayyy to much.